# Wordpress Permalink Rule Change Not Working

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Previously I have /%postname%/ permalink rule and just now I change it to /%category%/%postname%/ and now when somebody visit with the old URL then it shows 404. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: You need to set redirections, you can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea the rule to set that can acomodate my need?

Comment: Is there some logic on how previous post urls were so you can target them? If not, you should add redirection for each one by one. You didn't show any example, how many posts and categories are there? You can create a list of all those urls and in text editor add category slug, and then import that list as CSV in Redirections plugin. In Redirections plugin there are 2 input fields, first is the old url and it is relative to domain, second input field is absolute-full path for new url